# What is the most effective way to implement read/write process?

Tags: c#, multithreading, publish-subscribe

I'm looking for the best solution for this process. C# code reads a huge number of messages from IBM MQ queue, processes them and sends enhanced messages to ElasticSearch API.

The problem at the moment is that the time to process each message (there is no option for bulk operations) and send it to Elastic takes more time that fetch a message from IBM MQ.

I tried to run it with multithreading, in parallel, also with pub/sub in C# with ConcurrentQueue but the best result I get is still running all the process in sequence  (read -> enhance -> send). But it is not good enough for me because there are more messages coming to IBM MQ than I can handle with this solution and eventually I have a lot of untaken messages in IBM MQ.

What can be the better solution?

[image]

Comment: I would suggest start by *measuring*. How long time does the processing take? How many messages are received per second?  How large is each message? How long does it take to send?

Comment: I would expect that fetching messages takes less time than it takes to processing and writing it to the storage. I am not sure why you are expecting otherwise or maybe I am completely missing the point.

Comment: @tia I assume the question is how to speedup the processing/send steps so messages can be processed faster than they arrive.

Comment: @tia you are completely right and this is my problem. What is the best way to cope with this challenge.

Comment: See https://michaelscodingspot.com/performance-of-producer-consumer/

Answer (score 0):

After getting the measuring and analysis done, I solved the problem using `BlockingCollection` filled by the producer (from MQ) and a few consumers retrieving the data from the collection and saving it to `ElasticSearch`.